# Input Password - HTML5, Intel xdk, Cordova

Tags: html5, apache-cordova, input, intel-xdk

Estou tendo um problema com o `input type="password"`.

No Android o `input password` fica sempre iniciando com a letra maiúscula. Como faço para quando clicar no `input` a primeira letra já aparecer minúscula?

No IOS ele funciona corretamente. Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
<input type="password" name="senha" value="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Junior, tente usar o `autocapitalize` como `off`

```
<input type="password" name="senha" value="" autocapitalize="off">
```